# jQuery UI tabs in django templates

Tags: python, django, jquery-ui

I have template with many tabs (jQuery UI):

```
 <div>
     Satus: <span id="status_value"> {{  purchase.get_status_display }}</span>
     Owner: <span id="admin_value"> {{ purchase.owner }}</span> 
    </div>

    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tabs-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{% url purchase_info_tab %}">Purchase description</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url purchase_catalog %}">Purchase catalog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is view.py, first of I render main template, than using ajax render tab, In this case purchase_info_tab, for main template I need model Purchase and for purchase_info_tab I need model Purchase and we have two identical query. Сan I avoid this somehow?

```
@render_to('app/purchase_view.html')
def purchase_view(request, purchase_id):

    try:
        purchase = Purchase.objects.get(id=purchase_id)
    except Purchase.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404() 

    return {
        'purchase': purchase,

    }

@render_to('app/tabs/info_tab.html')
def purchase_info_tab(request):

    purchase = #I  load one model twice in one page

    try:
        itemsgroups = ItemsGroup.objects.filter(purchase=purchase).all()
    except IndexError:
        raise Http404()

    return {
           'itemsgroups': itemsgroups,
        }
```

Comment: would caching the `Purchase` object work?

Comment: how? one request one purchase

Answer (score 0):

From Django's point of view, your two views are entirely separate and you cannot share information between them without stashing it in some third location such as a URL parameter or session (remember that view methods may run even on different servers depending on how the application is deployed).

However, in the example you've given there is no need to.  You don't have to retrieve your purchase object to get the ItemsGroup: you can pass an ID into your query:

```
    itemsgroups = ItemsGroup.objects.filter(purchase__id=purchase_id).all()
```

Comment: "your two views are entirely separate and you cannot share information between them." Are you sure ? Sessions, cache, url parameters ... are solutions.

Comment: I think we're interpreting the question differently.  The question as I understand it was how to avoid the second query for Purchase.  I think you're interpreting it as how to remember *which* object was in hand from the first one.  You're suggesting storing the Purchase object somewhere else (in the session store), and then retrieving it, not necessarily any more efficient than just fetching it from the DB again.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to avoid this.

The easiest is to use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), as such:

```
@render_to('app/purchase_view.html')
def purchase_view(request, purchase_id):

    try:
        purchase = Purchase.objects.get(id=purchase_id)
    except Purchase.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404() 
    else:
        request.session['purchase'] = purchase

# [snip]

@render_to('app/tabs/info_tab.html')
def purchase_info_tab(request):

    purchase = request.session['purchase']

    # [snip]
```

Comment: This is racy: if the user opened two pages for different purchases simultaneously, the tab for one might load in the other.